Automated rig transfer between armatures
So I know how to manually transfer 1 armature to another mesh in blender.
See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bR_Vke__voU
But is there a way to do this automatically with python?
Its just pressing the same buttons over and over, can I just make function calls?

A answer pointing to where and how function calls are made and where I can lookup functions and specify there arguments would be ideal.
